# How to return different sets of duplicates from a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, duplicates

I have the following list of objects:

```
ConnectionType = ConnectionType.COM
ComPort = "com1"
TcpPort = null
ConnectionName = "CONN0"

ConnectionType = ConnectionType.COM
ComPort = "COM1"
TcpPort = null
ConnectionName = "CONN1"

ConnectionType = ConnectionType.COM
ComPort = "COM1"
TcpPort = null
ConnectionName = "CONN2"

ConnectionType = ConnectionType.COM
ComPort = "COM2"
TcpPort = null
ConnectionName = "CONN3"

ConnectionType = ConnectionType.IP
ComPort = null
TcpPort = 1234
ConnectionName = "CONN4"

ConnectionType = ConnectionType.IP
ComPort = null
TcpPort = 1234
ConnectionName = "CONN5"

ConnectionType = ConnectionType.IP
ComPort = null
TcpPort = 4321
ConnectionName = "CONN6"
```

Types used in each object:

```
private int? tcpPort;
private string comPort;
private string connectionName;
private ConnectionType connectionType;
```

What LINQ query would return a lookup/dictionary of duplicates for each ConnectionType? Results should include a ComPort/TcpPort and ConnectionName for each duplicate. As for ComPort, the query should match strings ignoring the case too.

So far I have been able to retrieve somewhat the desirable outcome with the following query:

```
var duplicates = myList
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.ComPort, x.TcpPort }).
            .Where(m => m.Key != null && m.Skip(1).Any());
```

Which returns the following:

```
{ ComPort = COM1, TcpPort =  }
     CONN1
     CONN2
{ ComPort = , TcpPort = 1234 }
     CONN4
     CONN5
```

However the result output should look like the following:

```
COM1
    CONN0
    CONN1
    CONN2

1234
    CONN4
    CONN5
```

Comment: What types are you using in your list?

Comment: Sound like a grouping operation you like to perform. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I have updated the question with types used in each object.

Comment: How about: `myList.GroupBy(x => x.TcpPort?.ToString() ?? x.ComPort)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following @SomeBody and @Jonathan Barclay suggestions, I was able to write the following query which produces the desired output:

```
var duplicates = myList
            .GroupBy(x => x.ConnectionType == ConnectionType.IP ? x.TcpPort?.ToString() : x.ComPort.ToUpperInvariant())
            .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any());
```

Thanks everyone for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this LINQ query:

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x.ConnectionType == ConnectionType.IP ? x.TcpPort : x.ComPort)
                  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(x => x.Key + "\n" + string.Join("\n",x.Select(y => "\t" + y.ConnectionName)));
```

First, we group by either the `TcpPort` or the `ComPort`, depending on the`ConnectionType`. Then we only use the groups with more than one item and finally format the string with the `Select` clause.

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CvvBvl

Comment: Thanks @SomeBody for your suggestion, however I'm getting the following compiler error :  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I believe this is due to the fact that TcpPort is not a string but a nullable int. I have updated the question with the correct types.